# How to access Node instance object from outside process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, instance, jsdom

I am trying to automate some testing for my web app using node + jsdom providing a headless browser instance. I spent a few days getting a node instance to join a session that was previously done manually via a test html stripped down page. This exposed the session object & its API to various test js files.

The issue right now is that Im not sure what's the best way to use this node instance to test my web app. The only immediate option I am seeing is to put the tests also on the node instance & have it set to run the tests after the session has been joined on node.

I have not done anything too advance with node before so I am wondering if there is a way to gain access to an node instance object from outside the process? 
Or maybe there's a better way of doing this that I cannot see

Comment: If the node instance is a web server, wouldn't you just send web requests to it and evaluate the responses you get?

Comment: might look into redis or zeromq or even repl

Comment: What I ended up doing was to making the session node instance into it's own module that could be easily used by the main test framework (which runs on node itself)